# Restoring Nuget References?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have solution & project in Visual Studio 2012.

The project has a file `packages.config` in the root of the project.

For the purposes of this question, lets assume I accidentally removed these libraries from the `References` section of my project.

When going into NuGet package manager, the interface is still reporting a tick next to these packages, indicating they are installed.

The only way I can see how to fix this situation is to delete all the entries from `packages.config`, which will fix the issue of the NuGet interface reporting them as installed, and re-add each one.

Is there a smarter way? I had hoped enabling 'enable nuget to restore missing packages' would solve this, but it doesnt seem to do anything.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

[Try re-installing the packages](http://www.overflowexception.es/2013/03/reinstalar-paquetes-de-nuget.html).

In the NuGet Package Manager Console enter the following command:

`Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName Your.Project.Name`

If you want to re-install packages and restore references for the whole solution omit the `-ProjectName` parameter.

Comment: English translation of the link: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.overflowexception.es%2F2013%2F03%2Freinstalar-paquetes-de-nuget.html

Comment: Note: This command will reinstall the references on *all* projects that are currently open in Visual Studio, rather than just the project selected in the console.

Comment: This command will reinstall packages in whole solution, not only in a selected project!

Comment: Extremelly Dangerous!!!! If the process gets interrupted, you will loss all your package references and will need to add one-by-one to every project in your solution.

Comment: @BillVelasquez this thing just ate all my references. Well, thank god for git, I guess.

Comment: Take note of the `-Project` switch which *will* only reinstall for the specific project identified.

Comment: The parameter -ProjectName XXXX is important in my case. Without that Nuget won't do anything on my specific project.

Comment: @Al-Muhandis: May be was due to some internet problems, because for me 30 packages were re-installed for a project in a approximately a couple of minutes as I targeted a new .net framework version.

Comment: @Bill -- If you're not using version control, today might be a good day to start.  In my opinion, the ability to undo changes or even scrap an environment and start fresh is almost essential.  Check out TFS or Git.

Comment: Another vital warning: this will not just reinstall the packages but upgrade you to later versions if they are available.

Comment: Should have read this last comment before running the command...Nuget packages get updated! What to do if I only want to restore?

Answer (score 45):

You need to [Enable NuGet package restore at the VS solution level](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) for the restore missing package to work.

[image]

Comment: This will allow NuGet to re-download missing packages into the .\packages\ directory, but has nothing to do with restoring missing *project references*, which is what the poster was asking about.

Answer (score 13):

In case this helps someone, for me, none of the above was sufficient. I still couldn't build, VS still couldn't find the references. The key was simply to **close and reopen the solution** after restoring the packages.

Here's the scenario (using Visual Studio 2012):

You open a Solution that has missing packages. The references show that VS can't find them. There are [many ways](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) to restore the missing packages, including

- building a solution that is set to auto-restore
- opening the Package Manager Console and clicking the nice "Restore" button
- doing `nuget restore` if you have the command line nuget installed

But no matter what the approach, those references will still be shown as missing. And when you build it will fail. Sigh. However if you close the solution and re-open it, now VS checks those nice `<HintPath>`s again, finds that the packages are back where they belong, and all is well with the world.

#### Update

Is Visual Studio *still* not seeing that you have the package? Still showing a reference that it can't resolve? Make sure that the version of package you restored is exactly the same as the `<HintPath>` in your .csproj file. Even a minor bug fix number (e.g. 1.10.1 to 1.10.2) will cause the reference to fail. You can fix this either by directly editing your csproj xml, or else by removing the reference and making a new one pointing at the newly-restored version in the packages directory.

Comment: You make a very important point about the restore only ensuring the packages are in the package folder (which of course can be many places).  However closing and re-opening was still not working for me even with the correct package versions, I ended up having to manually amend the hint paths in each csproj file.  I believe this is caused by moving the package folder relative to the project.

Comment: Editing the `.csproj` file to make sure version numbers matched worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

While the solution provided by @jmfenoll works, it updates to the latest packages. In my case, having installed beta2 (prerelease) it updated all of the libs to RC1 (which had a bug). Thus the above solution does only half of the job.

If you are in the same situation as I am and you would like to synchronize your project with the exact version of the NuGet packages you have/or specified in your `packages.config`, then, then this script might help you. Simply copy&paste it into your Package Manager Console

```
function Sync-References([string]$PackageId) {
  get-project -all | %{
    $proj = $_ ;
    Write-Host $proj.name; 
    get-package -project $proj.name | ? { $_.id -match $PackageId } | % { 
      Write-Host $_.id; 
      uninstall-package -projectname $proj.name -id $_.id -version $_.version -RemoveDependencies -force ;
      install-package -projectname $proj.name -id $_.id -version $_.version
    }
  }
}
```

And then execute it either with a sepific package name like

```
Sync-References AutoMapper
```

or for all packages like

```
Sync-References
```

Credits go to **Dan Haywood** and [his blog post](http://danhaywood.com/2012/04/04/updating-visual-studio-project-references-from-nuget-packages-config-2/).

Answer (score 8):

The following script can be run in the Package Manger Console window, and will remove all packages from each project in your solution before reinstalling them.

```
foreach ($project in Get-Project -All) { 
    $packages = Get-Package -ProjectName $project.ProjectName
    foreach ($package in $packages) {
        Uninstall-Package $package.Id -Force -ProjectName $project.ProjectName
    }
    foreach ($package in $packages) {
        Install-Package $package.Id -ProjectName $project.ProjectName -Version $package.Version
    }
}
```

This will run every package's install script again, which should restore the missing assembly references. Unfortunately, all the *other* stuff that install scripts can do -- like creating files and modifying configs -- will also happen again. You'll probably want to start with a clean working copy, and use your SCM tool to pick and choose what changes in your project to keep and which to ignore.

Answer (score 4):

This script will reinstall all packages of a project without messing up dependencies or installing dependencies that may have been intentianlyz removed.  (More for their part package developers.)

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName Proteus.Package.LinkedContent -IgnoreDependencies
```

Answer (score 3):

I added the DLLs manually. Right clicked on References in the project, select Add Reference and then in the dialog pressed the Browse button. The NuGet DLLs where in the packages directory of the solution. To get the names of them you can right click on references in another project that's working properly and select properties and look in the path property.

Comment: This is the simplest solution. It works for me by just browsing the packages folder.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015 (Soulution is under source control, MVC-Project), csano's `Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName Your.Project.Name` worked, but it messed up with some write locks.

I had to delete the "packages"-Folder manually before. (It seemed to be locked because of the source control).

Also, I had to re-install the MVC-Package from the NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone - In my scenario, I have some shared libraries (Which have their own TFS projects/solutions) all combined into one solution.

Nuget would restore projects successfully, but the DLL would be missing.

The underlying issue was that, whilst your solution has its own packages folder and has restored them correctly to that folder, the project file (e.g. .csproj) is referencing a different project which may not have the package downloaded. Open the file in a text editor to see where your references are coming from.

This can occur when managing packages on different interlinked shared solutions - since you probably want to make sure all DLLs are on the same level you might set this at the top level. This means it that sometimes it will be looking in a completely different solution for a referenced DLL and so if you don't have all projects/solutions downloaded and up-to-date then you may get the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with @Juri that the vastly popular answer by jmfenoll is not complete. In the case of broken references, I submit that most of the time you do **not** want to update to the *latest* package, but only fix your references to the *current* versions that you happen to be using. And Juri provided a handy function `Sync-References` to do just that.

But we can go just a bit further, allowing the flexibility to filter by project as well as package:

```
function Sync-References([string]$PackageId, [string]$ProjectName) {
    get-project -all | 
    Where-Object { $_.name -match $ProjectName } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $proj = $_ ;
        Write-Output ('Project: ' + $proj.name)
        Get-Package -project $proj.name |
        Where-Object { $_.id -match $PackageId } |
        ForEach-Object { 
            Write-Output ('Package: ' + $_.id)
            uninstall-package -projectname $proj.name -id $_.id -version $_.version -RemoveDependencies -force
            install-package -projectname $proj.name -id $_.id -version $_.version
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with missing references. Below my scenario:

- Fresh Windows 10 machine and VS Community 2015 install
- Just checked out repository code via TFS
- One solution built just fine, one solution had one project with missing references (EF, System.Http, as instance), but the relative nuget packages were properly installed.

All version numbers in project and packages match, doing nuget restore (in all its ways) did not work.

**How I fixed it:** simply delete the package folders in the solution root and execute nuget restore. At this point the dlls are correctly downloaded and can be added for the missing references.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy packages.config file of project and applies all version modify
2. Unistall all package and remove depencies

   ```
   $packages = Get-Package -ProjectName [nameOfProjectToRestore]
   foreach ($package in $packages) {
       uninstall-package  -projectname [nameOfProjectToRestore] -id $package.Id -version $package.version -RemoveDependencies -force ;
   }
   ```
3. Clear the packages folder in the root of project
4. Copy the modifies package.config to root folder of website
5. Run this code to restore the project

   ```
   $packages = Get-Package -ProjectName [nameOfProjectToRestore]
   foreach ($package in $packages) {
       uninstall-package  -projectname [nameOfProjectToRestore] -id $package.Id -version $package.version -RemoveDependencies -force ;
   }
   foreach ($package in $packages) {
       install-package  $package.Id -ProjectName [nameOfProjectToRestore] -Version $package.Version
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from this issue too a lot, in my case Downloading missing NuGet was checked (but it is not restoring them) and i can not uninstall & re-install because i modified some of the installed packages ... so:

I just cleared the cached and rebuild and it worked.
(Tools-Option-Nuget Package Manager - General)

also this link helps
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore.