# MVC Nuget Installing Multiple Packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm building a new solution/project.  I copied all the files over and moved all the packages over to the packages folder.  When I reference them via nuget, it says they are installed, but
they are not. If they were, I would see them in the installed tab.

First why does it say installed, next how can I install multiple packages at once, instead of
doing it individually.  I have like 10+ packages I need to install.  This is pain in 
the ass, if I have to install each individually.  We should be able to run a command that
checks to see if all the packages in the package folder have been installed, if not, install them.  Is there a command for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085480/restoring-nuget-references?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nuget.exe for this. see following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876732/how-do-i-get-nuget-to-install-update-all-the-packages-in-the-packages-config) and g[oogle search](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=nuget%20install%20missing%20packages)

```
nuget install packages.config
```

Or with NuGet 2.7 you can restore allpackages in the solution using the command line.

```
nuget restore YourSolution.sln
```