# Add references from copied package.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I want to copy `packages.config` of a project into newly created project and add reference with it in VS2015 SP3.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15304734/361100) introduces `Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName Your.Project.Name` but it does not work as I expected. Not all packages are added to project even though it has same build environment (.NET 4.5.2 Console App). Moreover, it overwrites `packages.config` to only added packages after the reinstall process.

How to do it correctly?

**+ Append** Below is my actual `packages.config` content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow" version="4.5.24" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" version="1.0.12" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="ncrontab" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Remotion.Linq" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SimpleInjector" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SimpleInjector.Extensions.ExecutionContextScoping" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SlowCheetah" version="2.5.15" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Interactive.Async" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) you can find the current documentation. Provide a minimal and reproducible example.

Comment: Could you please provide the package list in the packages.config and the version of NuGet Package Manager to me so that I can reproduce this issue? And make sure all packages can be downloaded from the Package Sources.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT // thanks. I added my `packages.config` content.

Comment: @Youngjae , any update for this question according to the below answer?

Comment: Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName worked for me in VS 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please accept the Reload or Reload All after the reinstall process complete.**

I got the same result after accept the Reload or Reload All to load the update project from disk in the process of reinstalling. Because your project is unload after accept the Reload or Reload All and the process of reinstalling is in progress. The packages could not be installed to the project during the project unload, NuGet will over write the package.config to only added packages before project unload.

The solution for this issue is that accept the Reload or Reload All after the reinstall process complete.

**Update**

There are different prompt for Conflicting File Modification Detected during the reinstalling. Please accept Reload or Overwrite after the reinstall process complete.
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, what does 'accept the Reload or Reload All' mean? is that a button or command?

Comment: Thanks. In addition, I found that _just_ running `ReInstall` nuget command 2~3 times make it right.